# Crear un tipo de archivo para mi aplicación

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación en python para costear proyectos, pero cada proyecto me toca guardarlo como .py, lo que quiero es hacer una aplicación principal y poder abrir cada proyecto desde la misma.

Es decir crear un archivo con una extensión y abrirlo desde mi aplicación, por decir así  como word abre archivos .docx, Excel abre .xlsx en fin.

Les quiero pedir el favor de orientarme por donde debo trabajar para llegar a ese objetivo.

Gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander,

Con el comando open('archivo.extension') puedes abrir cualquier archivo en texto plano (y binario si añades el argumento 'rb'), por ejemplo puedes llamar tu archivo: "configuracion.cfg".

Te dejo este recurso porque tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, y requiere un entendimiento más a nivel de curso que como pregunta individual.

https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/lectura-y-escritura-de-archivos/